# resolution of the following error?

Tags: c#, list

```
private static void VisualizarAgendaOrdenada()
{
    Pacientes.Sort();

    for(int i = 0; i <= Pacientes.Count; i++)
    {
        var agenda = Agendas.Find(p => p.Paciente.Nome == Pacientes[i].Nome);
        if (agenda != null)
        {
```

Error,

> "Index is out of bounds. Index cannot be negative or greater than the size of the collection."

Comment: I would highly suggest post everything you can in English, especially the error.

Comment: You are simply trying to access an element of the array outside the bounds of that array.

Comment: @Arran I thought all of us were multilingual?

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed, so trying to access the index which matches the length of the array is going one index too far.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop condition is wrong: you may not loop until `<= Pacientes.Count`, but only until `< Pacientes.Count`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Pacientes.Count; i++)
```

Otherwise you will try to access an index that is outside the range of the list. A list with `Count` elements is indexed from `0` to `Count-1`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read from the list under index which does not exist. Change your `<=` to `<`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Pacientes.Count; i++)
```

Because arrays/lists are indexed starting from `0` when you need to iterate over all elements you always have to use `< Count()` or `< Length`.